# How to match exactly 0.00 in regular expression in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex, datatables

I'm using DataTables to handle tables and I made a filters for columns that contain money data. Each filter is a select with two options, "Have" and "Not Have", where "Have" is when data in each cell of the column is different of 0.00 and "Not Have" is the opposite.

I made an example here:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var table = $('#example').DataTable();
  $('#select-input').on('keyup change', function() {

    var item = $(this)

    if ($(this).find('option:selected').val() === "1") {
      table
        .column(5)
        .search('^((?!0.00).)*$', true)
        .draw();
    } else if ($(this).find('option:selected').val() === "0") {

      table
        .column(5)
        .search('0.00')
        .draw();
    } else {
      table
        .search('')
        .columns().search('')
        .draw();
    }
  })
});
```

```css
body {
  font: 90%/1.45em "Helvetica Neue", HelveticaNeue, Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  color: #333;
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://nightly.datatables.net/css/jquery.dataTables.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://nightly.datatables.net/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <select id="select-input">
    <option value="">Select</option>
    <option value="1">Have</option>
    <option value="0">Not Have</option>
  </select>
  <table id="example" class="display nowrap" width="100%">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Position</th>
        <th>Office</th>
        <th>Age</th>
        <th>Start date</th>
        <th>Salary</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>

    <tfoot>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Position</th>
        <th>Office</th>
        <th>Age</th>
        <th>Start date</th>
        <th>Salary</th>
      </tr>
    </tfoot>

    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
        <td>System Architect</td>
        <td>Edinburgh</td>
        <td>61</td>
        <td>2011/04/25</td>
        <td>160.00</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Garrett Winters</td>
        <td>Director</td>
        <td>Edinburgh</td>
        <td>63</td>
        <td>2011/07/25</td>
        <td>30.00</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Ashton Cox</td>
        <td>Technical Author</td>
        <td>San Francisco</td>
        <td>66</td>
        <td>2009/01/12</td>
        <td>30.00</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Cedric Kelly</td>
        <td>Javascript Developer</td>
        <td>Edinburgh</td>
        <td>22</td>
        <td>2012/03/29</td>
        <td>30.00</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Jenna Elliott</td>
        <td>Financial Controller</td>
        <td>Edinburgh</td>
        <td>33</td>
        <td>2008/11/28</td>
        <td>30.00</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Brielle Williamson</td>
        <td>Integration Specialist</td>
        <td>New York</td>
        <td>61</td>
        <td>2012/12/02</td>
        <td>30.00</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Herrod Chandler</td>
        <td>Sales Assistant</td>
        <td>San Francisco</td>
        <td>59</td>
        <td>2012/08/06</td>
        <td>30.00</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Rhona Davidson</td>
        <td>Integration Specialist</td>
        <td>Edinburgh</td>
        <td>55</td>
        <td>2010/10/14</td>
        <td>31.00</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Colleen Hurst</td>
        <td>Javascript Developer</td>
        <td>San Francisco</td>
        <td>39</td>
        <td>2009/09/15</td>
        <td>31.00</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Sonya Frost</td>
        <td>Software Engineer</td>
        <td>Edinburgh</td>
        <td>23</td>
        <td>2008/12/13</td>
        <td>31.00</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Jena Gaines</td>
        <td>System Architect</td>
        <td>London</td>
        <td>30</td>
        <td>2008/12/19</td>
        <td>31.00</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Quinn Flynn</td>
        <td>Financial Controller</td>
        <td>Edinburgh</td>
        <td>22</td>
        <td>2013/03/03</td>
        <td>42.00</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Charde Marshall</td>
        <td>Regional Director</td>
        <td>San Francisco</td>
        <td>36</td>
        <td>2008/10/16</td>
        <td>53.00</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Haley Kennedy</td>
        <td>Senior Marketing Designer</td>
        <td>London</td>
        <td>43</td>
        <td>2012/12/18</td>
        <td>48.00</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Tatyana Fitzpatrick</td>
        <td>Regional Director</td>
        <td>London</td>
        <td>19</td>
        <td>2010/03/17</td>
        <td>28.75</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Michael Silva</td>
        <td>Senior Marketing Designer</td>
        <td>London</td>
        <td>66</td>
        <td>2012/11/27</td>
        <td>37.50</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Paul Byrd</td>
        <td>Javascript Developer</td>
        <td>New York</td>
        <td>64</td>
        <td>2010/06/09</td>
        <td>0.00</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

The problem is when selected option is "Not Have", numbers like 160.00 are been included in the result, and if option is "Have" the result is the opposite. What can I do?

Comment: _..regular expression in JavaScript..._ Why tag `php`? What have you tried?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```js
var x="160.00";
var y="0.00"
var z="0.001"
console.log("-------------with match--------------")
console.log(x.match(/^(0.00$).*/)?true :false)
console.log(y.match(/^(0.00$).*/) ? true :false)
console.log(z.match(/^(0.00$).*/)?true :false)
console.log("-------------with search--------------")
console.log(x.search(/^(0.00$).*/)>=0)
console.log(y.search(/^(0.00$).*/)>=0)
console.log(z.search(/^(0.00$).*/)>=0)
```

Comment: I'm using search in Datatables and it accepts regex, for example: table.column(col).search('^((?!0.00).)*$', true).draw();

Comment: This fails for `"0.001"`.

Comment: Then can you give spesific input for regex?

Comment: I'm making a column filter that is a select with 2 options, Have and Not Have, where have is when data in each cell of the column is different of 0.00 and Not Have the opposite

Comment: changed answer with regex @Cheyner

Comment: This fails for `"0x00"`. Also what is capture group supposed to achieve? And what is `.*` supposed to match?

Comment: With `/^(0.00$).*/` get all 0.00 but not 160.00, for example. And with `^(?!0.00$).*` get all data including 160.00 except 0.00. Thanks to @casasa90

Comment: @Cheyner You should escape the dots in both. A `.` in regex means "any character". Change them to `\.` which means a literal dot. Also the exact match could be `^0\.00$`. Or you could use `0.00` and set the second parameter of the `.search()` function to `false` so it doesn't use a regex.